# Weird behavior with $(SolutionDir) with msbuild in a .csproj file being wrong

Tags: msbuild

I have a .sln solution file that references a .csproj project file that has an after build task of something like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>
        xcopy $(SolutionDir)\dir1\Somefle.xml  $(ProjectDir) /Y /I
    </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The solution is built using msbuild with a task like the following:

```
<Target Name="CompileSolution">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Platform=Any CPU" />
</Target>
```

Now here's the strange part:

If I:

1. run the build script (say c:\MyWorkingCopy)
2. rename the working copy folder (say to c:\YourWorkingCopy)
3. run the build script again

On step 3, the xcopy will fail, because it will because it will be trying to copy the file from "c:\MyWorkingCopy" - which of course is not where the solution file now resides.

Why does msbuild use the old Solution directory?  And is there some way to reset it?

(I am using .NET Framework 3.5)

Comment: Are you renaming your working copy folder name somewhere during the execution of msbuild? Or I've missed something?

Comment: maybe msbuild creates a cache file that you should delete?

Comment: No, msbuild doesn't create any cache files with properties. But you didn't answer. Are you running msbuild once or twice in your scenario?

Comment: It may be related to the sln.cache file that is created by msbuild when you build a sln file (it's a temporary proj file built from the sln one), if it is present or if the sln is not modified the sln.cache file may be used... I don't really know but it I think it could help.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Sorry for the delay, I've been away for a few days. I'm not renaming the working copy build during the execution of msbuild.  The weird behavior I ran across is if it is run once - then the working copy renamed/moved, then msbuild run again.

Comment: @Nathan: I have no more ideas. Sounds totally like magic(

Comment: @Benjamin Baumann - you were correct.  If you want to convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I converted it although I have no deep understanding of the msbuild sln.cache process and I can't exactly explain your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be related to the sln.cache file that is created by msbuild when you build a sln file (it's a temporary proj file built from the sln one), if it is present or if the sln is not modified the sln.cache file may be used... I don't really know but it I think it could help.

Comment: the sln.cache files were indeed hanging around after the initial build.  Removing them resolved the problem.